# Why is this Time.parse failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
>> events.first.datetime
=> Wed Sep 15 19:00:00 -0400 2010
>> Time.parse(events.first.datetime)
NoMethodError: private method `gsub!' called for Wed Sep 15 19:00:00 -0400 2010:Time
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Time#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000305) creates a `Time` object out of a `String`, which it takes as its first argument. You already have a `Time` object, so `Time.parse` doesn't know what to do with it.

In order to format the date like you want it, take a look at [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298). You can format it like you want with the format string:

```
events.first.datetime.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p")
```

Take a look at the manual entry for `strftime` for other format specifiers.

Comment: i need to format it better like "Wednesday September 15, 2010 at 7:00pm"